# spark dataset wrong values when parallel job running on spark cluster environment

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using below setting

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Network Utilization Data")
                                .setMaster ("spark://10.126.228.139:7077")
                                .set("spark.submit.deployMode","cluster")
                                .set("spark.executor.instances","8")
                                .set("spark.executor.cores","4")
                                .set("spark.executor.memory","5120M")
                                .set("spark.driver.memory","5120M")
                                .set("spark.driver.memoryOverhead","10000M")
                                .set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
                                .set("spark.cores.max", "4");
```

I can run parallel job in spark cluster environment. But the dataset result for each job is giving wrong result. If i run single job, dataset result is correct.

Each job is performing different logic and different data source.

What might be the issue?

**If i run single job below is the dataset outcome.**

[image: Single Job Dataset result]

**if i run parallel job , dataset outcome is below.**  the extra values are from the other job dataset values.

[image: parallel dataset result]

Comment: What does the dataset look like? What do you mean by wrong values? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please provide steps for your dataset implementation.

Comment: updated with dataset result

Comment: Wanted to know the RDD actions and tranformations which you are using?

Answer (score 0):

we need to be careful at dataset writer. My two applications are writing into rf_table dataset.

ran_rf_dataset.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("rf_table");

That is why it is mixing data.

Now i assigned different dataset for each of the application to write. then data is ok.